# How to target a php created div with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to grab the first `<div>` of a set created by a php command, the problem is I can't seem to get the function to work or run after the divs have been created.

The php creates 5 `<div>`s when the page loads and i want to hide the first one.

Comment: Give it an ID or a class? Or if the container has one, navigate to the first child from there?

Comment: Essentially you need to be able to uniquely identify the element in order to target it with jQuery.  jQuery's selectors are pretty powerful, so it shouldn't be a problem.  But you'll need to know at least the shape of the HTML you're targeting.  ("Created by a PHP command" doesn't mean anything to jQuery, only the actual HTML.)

Comment: You should provide your sample source that is output.  You don't need to uniquely identify the element (i.e. with id attribute), but it helps. There are any number of other way to traverse the DOM to get at the element you seek.  We just have no way to give advice without seeing the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example I made to help you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>StackOverflow :: Help</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('div.mydiv:first').hide();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo "<div class='mydiv'>DIV 1</div>";
            echo "<div class='mydiv'>DIV 2</div>";
            echo "<div class='mydiv'>DIV 3</div>";
            echo "<div class='mydiv'>DIV 4</div>";
            echo "<div class='mydiv'>DIV 5</div>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can try this example and see that the first div is actually hidding when the page loads. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following, give each div a class, like this:

```
<div class="mydiv"></div>
```

After that, with jQuery you can hide the first div like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.mydiv:first').hide();
});
```

Comment: I am grabbing the first div and applying .hide to it using the jquery selector .first() but it doesn't do anything, tried in css and it won

Comment: I am grabbing the first child of the div series with the .first() and then applying .hide() but it won't work, doesn't work with css3 either using div.name:first:child {display:none;}    I don't know if the problem is that the divs are dynamically generated by php or what. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Yes i already have some other code that runs when document is ready so i just placed it in there, any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post you javascript and php code? It would be easier to help you.

Comment: solved!, i was missing an uppercase character, thanks to all! This community rocks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a unique `id`, you can get to the element like so:

```
<div id="div1"></div> <!--get this div -->
<div id="div2"></div>

$('#div1').hide();
```

Otherwise, if you have a class name associated with the group of `<div>`s, you can access the first one like so:

```
<div class="myClass"></div> <!--get this div -->
<div class="myClass"></div>

$('.myClass')[0].hide();
```

If you don't have any `class` or `id` for the `<div>`, you can access it like this: `var myDiv = $('div')[i];`, where `i` is the zero-based index number for the `<div>` that you want if you were to place all the `<div>`s in your webpage in order in an array. For example, if the `<div>` you want to access is the 2nd div that occurs on the page, you would access it using `var myDiv = $('div')[1];`

```
<div id="randomDiv"></div>

<div></div> <!--get this div -->
<div></div>

$('div')[1].hide();
```

As you might have noticed, the way you select elements by `id`, `class`, and `tag` in JQuery is identical to the way you would reference those items with CSS.

Comment: I am trying to make it work but can't, i think the problem is that the  divs are crated by php on my index.php page, i can't seem to target the first one of the 5 divs i'm creating through php. i am using the $('.myClass')[0].hide(); option but nothing works, please help!!! Thanks to all